# iPhone plays call ringtone over connected bluetooth speakers while on silent more

Tags: iphone

When I have my iPhone X on silent and I'm playing music through my Bluetooth speaker, if someone calls me I hear the ring over the speaker.

How do I stop this?

Answer (score 4):

[How To Stop Ringing Through the Bluetooth Speaker when the Music is On](https://innov8tiv.com/how-to-stop-ringing-through-the-bluetooth-speaker-when-the-music-is-on/)

> After connecting your phone to the Bluetooth device, go to your phone’s Settings then Bluetooth Settings. Under the section Bluetooth Paired Devices you will see two settings for the paired devices: phone audio and media audio. Uncheck the phone audio option. This will stop your phone from ringing while connected to the Bluetooth device (speaker) but the music will stop when a call rings.

Comment: Does this work for older models? I can't find that option in settings

Comment: @user27182 I think it shows only when you are connected to a Bluetooth device. Not complete sure what device you have . Also I have not tested all devices

Comment: Thanks. I have iphone 7. Couldnt find this option when i was connected to my speaker.

Comment: @user27182 I think that doesn’t work according to this Reddit [thread ](https://www.google.com/amp/s/amp.reddit.com/r/iphone/comments/64yd6t/anyway_to_keep_iphone_from_ringing_through/) your best bet I guess is to just use DND